# Get all field names and field types from Elasticsearch mappings recursively via Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, types

I am working on creating a python program that will validate the data that is imported into Elasticsearch.  The first step is to validate the data inserted into the index by comparing the datatype of the fields in the index to the data.  I am having a difficult time getting this programmatically via Python.  The original thought was to see if the datatype that was inputted equaled to what was mapped.  However, due to how ElasticSearch works, it would add a new field of the same name, but different datatype, correct? Should I rather be looking for a second occurrence of a field with a different datatype?

The mapping is defined and the data is then PUT into the index.  I can get the first layer of fields, but can't figure out how to get the deeper layers recursively.  I can't get all of the fields in all the layers.  The indexes have up to 4 layers in some areas.

This code will get me the first layer and then a dictionary of everything else, but I don't know how to get all the layers so I can programmatically query it.

The below code came essentially from this webpage, but as I said, it only gets the first layer and not any nested layers, and that is what I need.
[Get the mapping of an Elasticsearch index in Python](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/get-the-mapping-of-an-elasticsearch-index-in-python-880)

```
for (k,v) in schema.items():
    print(str(k) + ' : ' + str(v) + \n')
```

To get these fields programmatically, I'm not sure.

---

To create the mapping in ElasticSearch:

```
PUT index_name1
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "field1": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "field2": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "field3": {
                "properties": {
                    "field4": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "field5": {
                        "properties": {
                            "field6": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "field7": {
                                        "type": "long"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "field8": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "field9": {
                                "type": "date"
                            },
                            "field10": {
                                "type": "geopoint"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To see the mapping:

```
GET /index_name1/_mapping
```

To input data into index:

```
POST /index_name1/_doc/
{
  "field1": "hello_field_1",
  "field2": 12346.456898,
  "field3.field4": true,
  "field3.field5.field10": "POINT(-117.918976 33.812511)",
  "field3.field5.field6.field7": 366054524365,
  "field3.field5.field8": "field_of_dreams",
  "field3.field5.field9": "2021-07-26T07:47:26.133275Z"
}
```

Query the data just posted:

```
GET /index_name1/_search
```

To query the fields in Elasticsearch individually I would look at the field types in the mapping and then query each individual field.  I want to do this programmatically in Python querying each endpoint.
pseudocode:
if field1_type == type(field1):
continue
else:
print(error in field1)

Is there a field that never has data?
or perhaps let's say the geo_point field10 only has data if field4 ==true.  Check if it is empty.
or if field 7 has a certain value  then field 8 has a different value, is this accurate in the data? This logic is already in the data when it is populated.  I need to check if it is correct.

To look at these fields individually in ElasticSearch I would:

```
GET /index_name1/_search
{"query":{"match":{"field1":"index_name1"}}}

GET /index_name1/_search
{"query":{"range":{"field2":{"gt":30000}}}

GET /index_name1/_search
{"query":{"match":{"field3.field4":true}}}

GET /index_name1/_search
{"query":{"range":{"field3.field5.field6.field7":{"lt":40e+10}}}}

GET /index_name1/_search
{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all:{}},
{"filter":{distance":"500km","field3.field5.field10":"33,-117"}}}}}

GET /index_name1/_search
{"query":{"range":{"field3.field5.field9":{"gte":"now-365d/d","lt":"now/d"}}}}
```

i.e. if I want the value or type for field7, in Elasticsearch I would query it by:

```
GET /index_name1/_search
{
  "query":{
    "range":{"field3.field5.field6.field7":{"gt":366000000000}}
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the source of `schema`?  Are you reading that back from ElasticSearch?  I assume you've already dug around in these functions? https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.2.2/api.html#indices (I didn't see anything obviously useful there, but I'm an ElasticSearch noob, so might've missed it.)

Comment: I edited my submission and added the website where I got the code that I am using in my python code and which you are questioning. It doesn't look like the link worked, so here it is:
https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/get-the-mapping-of-an-elasticsearch-index-in-python-880